# Security in Hybrid cloud

Tags: security, cloud, amazon-ec2

How do we ensure security while setting up a hybrid cloud?

For example, if I want to use EC2 or Rackspace, how can I make sure that the connectivity between the private and the public cloud is secure?

Is a VPN necessary? If so, do we have to set it up manually?

Answer (score 1):

Will Amazon or Rackspace be hosting both your private and public cloud? If so, this would be a question for them. If you are personally managing a part of the cloud then you need to ensure that whatever distributed system architecture you're using to distribute workload uses secure means to transfer jobs/data/tasks. I doubt any modern distrib system architecture would send data over insecure channels, though.

In the off chance that the architecture does not support secure distribution of data, a VPN would be an easy and simple solution, though.